# ansible SSH connection fail

Tags: ssh, connection, ansible

I'm trying to run ansible role on multiple servers, but i get an error:

> fatal: [192.168.0.10]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg":
>   "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", "unreachable": true}

My /etc/ansible/hosts file looks like this:

```
192.168.0.10 ansible_sudo_pass='passphrase' ansible_ssh_user=user
192.168.0.11 ansible_sudo_pass='passphrase' ansible_ssh_user=user
192.168.0.12 ansible_sudo_pass='passphrase' ansible_ssh_user=user
```

I have no idea what's going on - everything looks fine - I can login via SSH, but ansible ping returns the same error.

The log from verbose execution:

> <192.168.0.10> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: user <192.168.0.10>
>   SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o
>   KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o
>   PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
>   -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=user -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 192.168.0.10
>   '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 22 && mkdir -p "`echo
>   $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1463151813.31-156630225033829`" &&
>   echo "`echo
>   $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1463151813.31-156630225033829`"
>   )'"'"''

Can you help me somehow? If I have to use ansible in local mode (-c local), then it's useless.

I've tried to delete ansible_sudo_pass and ansible_ssh_user, but it did'nt help.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to change the `ansible_ssh_pass` as well or ssh key, for example I am using this in my inventory file:

```
192.168.33.100 ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
```

After that I can connect to the remote host:

```
ansible all -i tests -m ping
```

With the following result:

```
192.168.33.100 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Hope that help you.

**EDIT**: `ansible_ssh_pass` & `ansible_ssh_user` don't work in the latest version of Ansible. It has changed to `ansible_user` & `ansible_pass`

Comment: Yes! I was missing the ansible_ssh_pass variable. Everything works like charm right now. Thank you so much!

Comment: According to http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html it should be `ansible_user` and not `ansible_ssh_user`.

Comment: If you search the `ansible_ssh_user` then you can find in the mentioned link, it was using in ansible 1.9 but in ansible 2.0 they have changed it to `ansible_user` but `ansible_ssh_user` is still valid in both.

Comment: The `hosts` file I had only has the IP address. After I suffixed it with `ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant ansible_ssh_user=vagrant`, ping started working. Thanks !!

Comment: @Matthias Those variables are for ssh module and for ansible 2.9 (the latest at the moment) both are good. Please, see [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/ssh.html#ssh-connection)

Answer (score 11):

```
mkdir /etc/ansible
cat > hosts
default ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222 ansible_ssh_user=vagrant ansible_ssh_private_key_file=.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

Go to your playbook directory and run ansible all -m ping or ansible ping -m "server-group-name"

Comment: Please, explain how answer addresses ssh connection problem.

Comment: This answer helped me with a similar issue to yours. Indeed, I was able to connect through plain ssh and even through ansible ping, but not launching a playbook. What helped me is the `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` attribute, because it is not located in the default dir.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue, but it was for a different reason than was documented in other answers. My host that I was trying to deploy to was only available by going through a jump box. Originally, I thought that it was because Ansible wasn't recognizing my SSH config file, but it was. The solution for me was to make sure that the user that was present in the SSH config file matched the user in the Ansible playbook. That resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Exactly right. After changing the `remote_user: root` to match the user in the `.ssh/config` it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify your host file to:

```
192.168.0.10
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12
```

Answer (score 1):

`$ansible -m ping all -vvv`

After installing ansible on Ubuntu or CentOS.
You can have messages below. Do not panic, you must have an access right to the file `/tmp` of user [`/home/user_name/.ansible/tmp/`].
"`Authentication or permission failure`".

This preconisaion will solve the problem.

```
[Your_server ~]$ ansible -m ping all
rusub-bm-gt | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
Your_server | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice for me I'm using SSH keys to access to server hosts

1.Create hosts file in inventories folder

[example]

example1.com

example2.com

example3.com

2. Create ansible-playbook file playbook.yml

---

- hosts:

- all

- roles:

- example

3. let's try to deploy ansible-playbook with multiple server hosts

ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventories/hosts example --user vagrant

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by following [the sulition provided in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66491309/12025859).

Basically, append the content of `id_rsa.pub` file, into the `authorised_keys` file.

Answer (score -1):

The ansible_ssh_port changed while reloading the vm.

==> default: Booting VM...

==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...

```
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222

default: SSH username: vagrant

default: SSH auth method: private key
```

So I had to update the inventory/hosts file as follows:

```
default ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222 ansible_ssh_user='centos' ansible_ssh_private_key_file=<key path>
```

Comment: Please, explain what answer has to do with ssh connection problem and why vagrant on localhost is relevant.