# UNREACHABLE error while running an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I do have access to ssh into the destination machine, and it works, but whenever I run this playbook, I get this error output:

```
sudo ansible-playbook ansible-playbook-test.yml

PLAY [openstack] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [amachine]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
        to retry, use: --limit @/blah/ansible-play/ansible-playbook-test.retry

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
amachine       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

My playbook is as simple as this:

```
---
# hosts could have been "remote" or "all" as well

- hosts: openstack
  tasks:
    - name: test connection
      ping:
      remote_user: djuarezg
      vars:
        ansible_ssh_extra_args: '-K -o ControlPath=none'



- hosts: openstack
  tasks:
    - name: Create Swarm cluster
      command: mkdir djg
      vars:
        ansible_ssh_extra_args: '-K -o ControlPath=none'
```

I was trying to use `ansible_ssh_extra_args: '-K -o ControlPath=none'` to see if it was able to forward the Kerberos ticket, but any kind of connection is enough.

Comment: Do you have python installed on the target/remote machine?

Comment: how is the ssh authentication supposed to work? u have ssh-keys exchanged for user `djuarezg`?

Comment: Probably you should run `ansible-playbook` without `sudo`, to use your SSH keys or another your credentials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ ansible-playbook --user=djuarezg -vvv ansible-playbook-test.yml
```

Check SSH args in the output

Answer (score 6):

**This worked for me:**

```
$ cd /root/.ssh
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

save key under the name of id_rsa

```
$ cat id_rsa.pub
```

copy the entire key and paste in file (of master node located at path: /.ssh/ or /root/.ssh) as:

```
$ sudo nano authorized_keys
```

Then run this to check:

```
$ ansible all -m ping -u root
```

Output should be like this:

```
master-node | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Was trying to install diaspora on an Rpi and this got me unstuck from that same unreachable error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with large host inventories through jumpboxes.
Mine was set high to speed up large plays but it didn't play nicely when introducing a jump box and I hit this random Unreachable issue.

The solution was to reduce the amount forks.
15 was okay but 10 was the sweet spot for my env...

Answer (score 1):

Adding user designation fixed it for me - `-u deploy`

```
ansible-playbook [...yml] -u deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo cd /root/.ssh

$ sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

save the key under the name of id_rsa

```
$ sudo cat id_rsa.pub
```

copy the entire key and paste it in the file of control node eg: vi authorized_keys

```
$ sudo vi authorized_keys
```

Then run this to check:

`$ ansible myhosts -m pring -i inventory.ini` (Assuming your inventory name is "inventory.ini and your host name is myhosts")
Output should be like this:

```
3.10.58.139 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```