# Failed to connect to the host...permission denied (publickey, password) unreachable

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm finding it difficult to run a simple playbook. I already ping target and it was successful. When i run the playbook i get this error:

```
PLAY [install httpd and start services] ***********************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************
fatal:[192.168.112.66]: UNREACHABLE!=> {"changed": false "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: jay@192.168.112.66: Permission denied (publickey password)." "unreachable": true}
```

What's the problem with this?

Comment: One issue could be that the ssh private key which is present already can't be access by the user from which ansible playbook is run. Make sure that the ansible user configured in ansble.cfg or the host file (with ansible_ssh_private_key_file defined) has permission to access user `jay` 's ssh key.

Comment: Try adding -vvv in the ansible command to get the detailed logs

Comment: now i get a different error, saying:   failed to connect to the host via ssh: could not resolve hostname target: Temporary failure in name resolution", "unreachable: true"

Answer (score 2):

The remote server is denying you the access due your key has a password.
Try this before run the playbook:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent`
$ ssh-add /path/to/your/private/key
```

Then run the playbook with the options -u and --private-key pointing to the user with access permissions on remote server and the private key you use.

Comment: i tried everything and now i'm getting a different error message.  something like this: {"changed"; false, "msg": invalid/incorrect password: Permission denied please try again." "unreachable": true}

Comment: Ensure your target server allows ssh login with keys, not just passwords. If it's asking for password maybe you're not allowed to login with ssh keys

Comment: If that should be the case then please how do i ensure my target server allows ssh login with keys instead of passwords?

Comment: @ Victor - I added the SSH keys to the remote server using; ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub blast@192.168.4.5 and still yet if i try to run my playbook it shows permission denied (publickey password). why same error?

Comment: Can you login to remote server only with your key? Your key has a passphrase? Review options 'PubkeyAuthentication' on sshd config of your remote server

Comment: @ Victor, i'm new to using Ansible, i did not use password to login to the remote server since i already have a sshkey. And on sshd config i set 'PubkeyAuthentication' is no. Is that so?

Comment: yeah, that's it! you should allow public key authentication

Comment: finally i got the answer and it worked perfectly. i changed the playbook file permission to execute. chmod +x (playbook.yml)

Answer (score 2):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75977328/12025859).

Basically, append the content of `id_rsa.pub` file, into the `authorised_keys` file.

Comment: Wondering why I got "-1". Appreciate if someone letting me know what was wrong with the solution. It worked for me and I share it to help others.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you used a password instead of ssh-key. So at the end of your command, add

`--ask-pass`

Let's say you're running your playbook. Your command will become:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --ask-pass
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@remote-host

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers given above solved the issue for me, so I have to come up with something else. The following steps helped me to run an ansible playbook on a remote host:

1. Generate a ssh key pair using `ssh-keygen`
2. Add the generated public key using `ssh-copy-id` or manually.
3. Create an inventory file at `/etc/ansible/hosts` and configure the remote host:

   ```
    [testservers]
    <remote-host-ip-address> ansible_user=<user-name> ansible_ssh_private_key_file=<absolute-path-to-your-public-ssh-key>
   ```
4. Run your ansible playbook